# Router Outlet Inside router outlet in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am Using router outlet inside another router outlet with different name.

```
{

[routerLink]='{ outlets: { "childRouter": ["one-way"] } }'>One Way

[routerLink]='{ outlets: { "childRouter": ["return"] } }'>Return

[routerLink]='{ outlets: { "childRouter": ["multicity"] } }'>Multicity

}
```

And in my Route :

```
{ 
  path: 'flights', 
  component: FlightsComponent,
  data: { animation: 'flights' },
  children: [
     { path: 'one-way', component: FlightOneWayComponent, data: { animation: 'one-way' }, outlet: 'childRouter'},
     { path: 'return', component: FlightReturnComponent, data: { animation: 'return' }, outlet: 'childRouter'},
     { path: 'multicity', component: FlightMulticityComponent, data: { animation: 'multicity' }, outlet: 'childRouter'},
]},
```

I am using `<router-outlet name="childRouter"></router-outlet>` in my main component.

It is working properly but it generates the path like `/flights/(childRouter:one-way)`.

Is there any way to change the path like `flights/one-way` rather than `(childRouter:one-way)`?

Answer (score 0):

the technique you used is to implement a secondary route,
you don't need it in your case

try this instead:

juste remove the outlet part from here

```
 { path: 'one-way', component: FlightOneWayComponent, data: { animation: 'one-way' }},
 { path: 'return', component: FlightReturnComponent, data: { animation: 'return' }},
 { path: 'multicity', component: FlightMulticityComponent, data: { animation: 'multicity' }},
```

and use this instead:

```
[routerLink]='["one-way"]'>One Way
[routerLink]='["return"]'>Return
[routerLink]='["multicity"]'>Multicity
```

Comment: but i want to use it in such a way as i have a structure something like a tab and i don't want to put all the three forms in a same component. I want to load a component on click of that tab only. So in that case it is working fine. My main concern is that the url generated is different I want to modify that.